# the docstring popup from Jedi-vim gets written to my doc instead of just popping up and disappearing

Tags: vim, jedi-vim

the docstring popup from Jedi-vim gets written to my doc instead of just popping up and disappearing. I have the same flavor of VIM and JEDI on another box, works fine. Any ideas?

Versions

```
jedi-vim: latest as of this post
Vim / Neovim:
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 17 2016 06:26:47)
Included patches: 1-488, 576
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Python: Python 2.7.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed here:

https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/pull/646

Just update jedi-vim.

Comment: Thanks. I had posted a git issue and they solved it.